# Check if user has typed something while script is running

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have to write a script that prints every three seconds the % of CPU used by user or by system. If the user types a specific string, the output must switch back and forth.

How can I check for input without interrupting the output stream? 
The read command would stop it, I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the read command with the timeout option `read -t`. For example the below script detects the string 'cc'. You can also specify the number of characters to read with `-N` so that user does not have to press enter.

```
flag=0
while true; do
    sleep 3
    if [[ $flag -eq 0 ]];then
      echo user
    else
      echo sys
    fi
    read -t 0.25 -N 2 input
    if [[ $input = "cc" ]] ; then
       [[ $flag -eq 0 ]] && flag=1 || flag=0
    fi
done
```

Comment: Read takes only integer arguments (seconds) for `-t`.  Otherwise, this is a good solution.  I don't think we need the `-N` option - just `-t` is enough.

Comment: @codeforester Fraction of second with `-t` works fine for me

Comment: Thank you, it worked, I had to put the `sleep` command in the first 'if' construct though.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get information to your script by creating files.  It sounds like your program has a loop and a sleep.  Why not check for the existence of a file?

```
[ -r control.file ] && change_behavior
```

Comment: The user will type while the script is running and printing the information, whenever they want, I'm not sure on how using files would help.

Comment: If 'top' is a good example of an interactive program that you are describing, then you might consider reviewing the 'curses' library (or 'ncurses' library).  While this is not bash (it's c), you may find the ability to interact asynchronously with the keyboard.